# Unable to resolve 112.0: missing requirement [112.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.framework)(version>=1.8.0))

Tags: maven, osgi, osgi-bundle, karaf

I am creating a simple Echo service bundle in apache Karaf 3.0.3, I have my Activator class,

```
package com.company.activator;

import org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator;
import org.osgi.framework.BundleContext;

public class Activator implements BundleActivator {

    private static BundleContext context;

    static BundleContext getContext() {
        return context;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     *
     * @see org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator#start(org.osgi.framework.BundleContext)
     */
    public void start(final BundleContext bundleContext) throws Exception {
        Activator.context = bundleContext;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     *
     * @see org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator#stop(org.osgi.framework.BundleContext)
     */
    public void stop(final BundleContext bundleContext) throws Exception {
        Activator.context = null;
    }
```

I am able to create the Bundle Via eclipse, with the following Mannifest file

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Private-Package: com.company.activator
Built-By: noushad
Tool: Bnd-0.0.238
Bundle-Name: osgi
Created-By: Apache Maven Bundle Plugin
Build-Jdk: 1.7.0_76
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0
Bnd-LastModified: 1427119505629
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Activator: com.company.activator.Activator
Export-Packages: com.company.echo
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.company.osgi
Import-Package: org.osgi.framework;version="1.8"
```

Also I have the following POM file

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>osgi</artifactId>
    <packaging>bundle</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>osgi Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>osgi</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.0</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <instructions>
                        <Bundle-SymbolicName>${pom.groupId}.${pom.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                        <Bundle-Name>${pom.artifactId}</Bundle-Name>
                        <Bundle-Version>1.0.0</Bundle-Version>
                        <Private-Package>com.company.activator</Private-Package>
                        <Bundle-Activator>com.company.activator.Activator</Bundle-Activator>
                        <Export-Packages>com.company.echo</Export-Packages>
                        <Import-Package>*</Import-Package>
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Also my Echo Class

```
package com.company.echo;

public class Echo {

    public String echo(final String string) {
        return string;
    }
}
```

I face the following problem(s) when i deploy this application on the karaf 3.0.3

1. Getting the following stack trace when I try to start the bundle

   ERROR: Bundle com.company.osgi [112] Error starting/stopping bundle. (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle com.company.osgi [112]: Unable to resolve 112.0: missing requirement [112.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.framework)(version>=1.8.0)))
   org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle com.company.osgi [112]: Unable to resolve 112.0: missing requirement [112.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.osgi.framework)(version>=1.8.0))
       at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:3974)
       at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2037)
       at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setBundleStartLevel(Felix.java:1483)
       at org.apache.felix.framework.FrameworkStartLevelImpl.run(FrameworkStartLevelImpl.java:334)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Could Some body help me to figure out what the exact problem is.

Thanks in advance..!

Comment: Also I have the following texts got from the web console : Imported Packages org.osgi.framework,version=1.8 -- Cannot be resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think karaf 3 supports OSGi Core R6 (org.osgi.framework package version 1.8). You should try compiling against an other version of the OSGi API.

Comment: Thanks @BJ Hargrave , It worked!.. I changed the version to 5.0.0 :)